# Is there a john doe of the internet (not anonymous)?

Tags: anonymity

Anonymous is one of the most interesting things in culture these days (imo), but if one were to make anything and put the name "Anon" on it, it might come off as either undesirable to the loosely organized Anonymous, or self targeting as part of a larger threat.

Is there a more name like, possibly comedic, widely used filler for unknown people?  Something like "Bob Dole, or John Madden, or John Doe."  Where it's not "legion" political but is still used enough it's hard to glean anything from it?

Maybe some past famous hacker...

Basically, something anonymous that isn't "Anonymous"

Comment: There are also other placeholder in English but it is different from language to language. The german equivalent of John Doe is Max Mustermann. John Doe is also used in the internet. Anon comes from 4chan.

Comment: This is vaguely related to InfoSec. Perhaps a meta-site or other discussion site would prove to fit better for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alice and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) are widely accepted placeholders for describing interactions in an information security context.

Bob and Alice are generally legitimate entities, but there's a whole suite of associated names which are attached to certain types of attackers or involved parties. For example Mallory is used for a general malicious entity or Eve for a man-in-the-middle (eavesdropper).

I wouldn't use these terms to describe a specific unknown entity in a specific scenario, but if you were describing the sequence of events in abstract terms then they might be appropriate.